# Docusign REST API to add documents to existing envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently creating a envelope with a few documents and sending it out for signing using the REST API.I have a new requirement where I first need to create the envelope in draft with no documents.Later update the envelope with a few documents and send it out for signing.I cant find the documentation for attaching docs to an existing create status envelope.
Can I do PUT on  https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts//envelopes//documents with all my base64 encoded documents?
I remember seeing something like this before in the Docs but can no longer find the documentation for this use case.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- [EnvelopeDocuments:update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/update/) adds one document to the envelope
- [EnvelopeDocuments:updateList](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/updatelist/) adds one or more documents to the envelope